# Pods fetchRecord skips items

Tags: php, wordpress, podscms

So I have am grabbing some records using Pods.
I have 31 records, but my `while($thePod->fetchRecord())` loop only goes 15 times

```
$thePod = new Pod('projects');
$thePod->findRecords('slider_order ASC');
$totalItems = $thePod->getTotalRows(); // = 31

while($thePod->fetchRecord()) :
  $i++;

endwhile;

echo $i.'/'.$totalItems.' looped through'; // displays 15/31
```

Any ideas why this is occuring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change line 2 to:

```
$thePod->findRecords('slider_order ASC',-1);
```

15 is the default records per page, -1 returns all records.